# Angular material sidenav and fixed toolbar

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I copied this sidenav demo from the angular material docs.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav

And added the first toolbar demo to it from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar

What I want is the toolbar to be fixed.

Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/gvorster/pen/BzWvGe

When adding this style the toolbar is fixed.

```
<md-toolbar class="md-hue-2" style="position:fixed !important">
```

But the icons on the right are gone.

[image]

Resizing the screen until the sidenav is hidden will show the right side icons.

[image]

Removing the style shows the right side icons but the toolbar is not fixed:

[image]

Is there a way to get a sticky toolbar and have the rigth side icons shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `md-sidenav` inside the `md-content` container. Plus try to use `md-content` instead of `div` tag. In your example you gave wrong values to `layout-align` attribute. Please check the appropriate values in the [Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment).

Here is the basic structure for your requirement.

```
<md-content flex>
    <md-toolbar>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content layout="column" layout-fill>
        <!-- content -->

        <md-sidenav>
        </md-sidenav>
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```

here is the working pen. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/xOqMjy

Comment: Is there a way to do this with material for angular 2? It doesn't appear that md-content exists and I'm having the exact same issue as @Guus.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add layouts for all containers and move the toolbar out of the md-content that should be scrolled.

```
<div layout="row" flex>
 <md-sidenav></md-sidenav>
 <div layout="column" flex>
   <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
   <md-content></md-content>
 </div>
 <md-sidenav></md-sidenav>
</div>
```

Here's a working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyWJKK?editors=1010